# PHP returns strange error from CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Does anyone know why I always get this error:

```
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
```

when I try to call PHP from CLI?

Is there any chance to disable loading this module?

Any experience with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search would give you Scripty's link, but it wont disable the module. Your php (cli) is trying to a load a module that can't be initialized. To disable it, look for the ini file that loads the libdc1394*.so (* stands for any number of characters) file in the php/conf.d directory. To find it, in a typical default install of Linux, run this command :

```
grep .so /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/*.ini
```

This will give you list of file names and the ".so" files they load. If you spot the right extension, open the conf file and add a '#' in front of the line that starts with 'extension='

```
#extension=libdc1394*.so
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Adil, I have tried this one:

# grep extension /etc/php.d/*.ini

But it seems that no extension like "libdc" is loaded there. Any idea?

Jakub

Comment: It could be that the module has a different name. A quick google search returns that its a driver for IEEE 1394 compatible cameras (http://cblfs.cross-lfs.org/index.php/Libdc1394).

It may also be the case that your php came precompiled with that module. In which case i'd suggest you download one from php.net

Comment: libdc1394.so is not loaded from any 'extension=libdc1394.so' configuration (at least in my CentOS 6.3 Final). After some search I figured out that the 'facedetect.so' is linked with libdc1394.so (ldd /usr/lib64/php/modules/facedetect.so | grep libdc1394). Maybe you need to download from source and re-build the facedetect extension without the libdc1394 support (google it for how to do it).